# Darken/color a selected element (content-box) and add a check-mark-icon AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

My question is related I think to jquery, angularjs and bootstrap.

I am rendering information that is coming from the backend and is presented on the front end in the form of several boxes. I am trying to get an "element selection effect" that when someone clicks on one or more of the boxes the entire box gets darker (or preferably blue with some level of transparency) and an ok-checkmark appears on it. The element is actually a bootstrap Well with some content inside.

I currently have an onClick event that colors the background, but it is not enough. Unlike an image, that can be entirely darkened when changing the background color, with a well (or any content box) it just colors the background and the content is still visible. I also want to add that green checked-mark icon inside the box when clicked, but I do not know how to add elements on the fly after onClick event.

Here is my relevant pieces of code (simplified objects, no backend):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.collections = [
    {text:'content collection1'},
    {text:'content collection2'}];
  $scope.selectBox = function(collection){

    collection.isclicked =! collection.isclicked;
    $("#well").click(function(){
      if (collection.isclicked){
        //$("div").append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok pull-right"></span>');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.well:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  cursor:hand;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
} 

.well {
 
 border-color:#8CC63F;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 20px;
 
}

.well-active {
  
 background-color:#3399ff;
 
}

.well-active:hover {
  
 background-color:#3399ff;
 
}
```

```html
<div data-ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
  <div data-ng-repeat="collection in collections" data-ng-init="collection.isclicked=false">
    <div class="well" data-ng-click="selectBox(collection)" data-ng-class="{'well-active': collection.isclicked}">
      <div>{{collection.text}}</div>                  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as I mentioned, the way it works now is that the selected wells change their background color, but that's it. How do I darken/color the entire well, including the content, and how do I add an icon on top of that background (inside the well) after mouse-click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an ng-show/ng-hide in elements inside of the well div:

```
<div data-ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
  <div data-ng-repeat="collection in collections" data-ng-init="collection.isclicked=false">
    <div class="well" data-ng-click="selectBox(collection)" data-ng-class="{'well-active': collection.isclicked}">
      <span ng-hide="collection.isClicked">{{collection.text}}</span>
      <i ng-show="collection.isClicked" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>                                     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will show the content if the collection is not checked, and a check mark if the collection is checked.

Comment: It works great! Such a simple and short solution, thanks!